# Problem with RESTApi with multiple client call

Tags: rest, web-services, jersey, synchronization

I am new in rest and trying to write a simple rest api which transfer some amount from one source to another. I do not have database,  using a map as a datasource. My service simply checks if source has enough amount to transfer, if so then I update both source and target. Problem is I concern about multiple request at the same time. Because when there is a multiple request, they can both do validation at the same time with the same source values which cause a wrong behaviour.

Example: Source has amount 100 and there are 2 request to transfer by amount 70. Processing both request, they both check at the same time that source has amount of 100 then they can perform transfer.

1) My resource:

```
 public class MyResource {

    @Inject
    TransferService transferService;


    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Transfer transfer(Transfer transfer){

        return transferService.transfer(transfer);
    }
}
```

2) Source POJO

```
public class Source {

    private String sourceId;
    private double balance;

    ....

}
```

3) Source Service

```
public class SourceServiceImp implements SourceService {


    @Override
    public Source getSource(String sourceId) {

        Source source = EmbeddedSources.getSource(sourceId);

        return source;

    }


    public boolean deposit(String sourceId, double amount ){

        Source source = getSource(sourceId);
        source.setBalance(source.getBalance() + amount);

        EmbeddedSources.updateSource(sourceId, source);
        return  true;
    }


    public boolean withdraw(String sourceId, double amount ){

        Source source = getSource(sourceId);
        source.setBalance(source.getBalance() - amount);

        EmbeddedSources.updateSource(sourceId, source);
        return  true;
    }


}
```

4) TransferService

```
public class TransferServiceImpl implements TransferService {


    private static SourceService sourceService ;


    public TransferServiceImpl(SourceService sourceService){
        this.sourceService = sourceService;
    }


    @Override
    public Transfer transfer(Transfer transfer) {

        Source sourceSource = sourceService.getSource(transfer.getSourceSourceId());
        Source destSource = sourceService.getSource(transfer.getDestSourceId());
        double amount = transfer.getAmount();



        if(isBalanceEnough(sourceSource, destSource, amount)){
            sourceService.withdraw(sourceSource.getSourceId(), amount);
            sourceService.deposit(destSource.getSourceId(), amount);     
        }

        transfer.setStatus("VALID");
        return transfer;

    }

}
```

5) Embedded DB

```
public class EmbeddedSources {

    private static Map<String, Source> sourceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static Map<String, Transfer> transferMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    public static Source getSource(String sourceId){
        return sourceMap.get(sourceId);
    }

    public static void updateSource(String sourceId, Source source){
        sourceMap.put(sourceId, source);
    }


    public static void addSource(Source source){
        sourceMap.put(source.getSourceId(), source.deepCopy());
    }

}
```

I thought about using queue for request but I believe it is not good solution. Also I thought about using volatile for source class fields but still it won't prevent the problem of multiple request for same sourceId.

How can I prevent this problem and make service safe for multiple request?

Comment: Have a look at multithreading and producer-consumer problem.

Comment: I thought about it by using queue but in that case every request will be processed one by one , when there is something in the queue. I am just not sure it will be efficient enough.

Comment: You can use synchronized methods for the withdraw and deposit methods, so that any modification to your balance is performed sequentially.